# Retrieve value of input tag before form is submitted

Tags: php, html, forms

My HTML code has an input tag where the user can enter data (a number).  As soon as they leave that tag (after inputting their data) I need to immediately retrieve that value so I can do some math using the number.

I plan to use the form event "onchange" (fires the moment when the value of the element is changed) to call a PHP function that will perform the calculation.  All of this needs to happen way before the form is submitted.

I can't figure out how to retrieve the new input tag value using PHP.  Surely the key is via the name attribute of the input tag.

```
<input type="text" name="numAEBs" value="0" />
```

The default value is zero.  When the user changes it to something else, how can I retrieve the new value of input tag named "numAEBs"?

Thank you very much for your help with this.

Comment: Using jQuery, something along the lines of `$('input[name="numAEBs"]').change(function(){ ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

As you and @Amal said, you'd be using the onchange event.

Well, onchage, you could retrieve the value of an input field using:

```
$("input[numAEBs]").val();
```

And you can store this in a variable using

```
var val = $("input[numAEBs]").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it would be better to use JavaScript to retrieve form value. PHP is for server-side processsing. It's not suited for this.

Use

```
document.<formname>.<input_tag_name>.value
```

Answer (score 1):

It is suggested that you should use javascript to do the calculation and then make a new hidden field, which will have the new calculated value in that field and then in the php code retrieve that value instead of the original value.

Code:

```
<input type="text" name="numAEBs" value="0" onchange="document.FORM NAME HERE.finalnumAEBs.value = document.FORM NAME HERE.numAEBs.value DO WHATEVER CALCULATIONS YOU WANT TO DO HERE;" />
<input type="hidden" name="finalnumAEBs" value="0" />
```

And retrieve the final value like this:

```
$numAEBs = $_POST['finalnumAEBs'];
```

Hope it works.